# Why are these characters brothers, yet so different?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

I just watched The Eternals yesterday and got surprised by the first post credit scene.

In it we can see :

> Eros, Thanos' brother

**How can he be so different from his brother ?**

I know that for now we don't have much information from the MCU itself but the background will probably be roughly the same as in the comics, so I would like this version of the story.

Comment: I believe Thanos is a mutant among Titans. In  Infinity War we see his projection of what Titan used to look like and the Titans in the background do not look like him but rather more traditionally human.

Comment: I've closed as a dupe and set a bounty on the target to hopefully draw a better answer to it.

Comment: Siblings can be very different. Also, the Eternals we see in the movie are basically biological robots created by the Celestials for a specific mission. Titans' Eternals have probably a similar genesis. Earth's Eternals are not designed to be blood-related, so why Eros and Thanos are brothers is a mystery.

Comment: This could be a Loki/Thor-type situation.